# Improving missing value removing code in R

Tags: r

I have to remove 0 or -ve values from a vector of time series. An example of a vector of time series is given below:

```
c(-1856, -1770, -1787, 1322, 1605, 1417, 1423, 1371, 1200, 1295, 1441,    587, 189, 330, 1133, 1398, 1455, 100, 455, 59, 222, 330, 289, 251, 1717,   1258, 1732, -3258)
```

-ve values and 0 values are treated as missing values and it should be replaced by the mean of immediate neighbors (non-missing value). As for example in the vector above missing/-ve values will be replaced by the mean of `(1322 and 1732)`.

The output will be as follows

```
1527, 1527, 1527, 1322, 1605, 1417, 1423, 1371, 1200, 1295, 1441,  587,  189,  330, 1133, 1398, 1455,  100,  455,   59,  222,  330,  289,  251, 1717, 1258, 1732, 1527
```

There may be multiple cases of missing values and edge cases should also be considered. Some of the examples are given below.

```
Vector ending with -ve value

x = c(1856, 1770, 1787, 1322, 1605, 1417, 1423, 1371, 1200, 1295, 441,   587, 189, 330, 1133, 1398, 1455, 100, 455, 59, 222, 330, 289, 251, 1717,   1258, 1732,-3258)

Vector with multiple missing values

x = c(1856, 1770, 1787, 1322, 1605, 1417, 1423, 1371, 1200, 1295, 441,   587, 189, 330, 1133, 1398, 1455, -100, -455, -59, -222, -330, -289, 251, 1717,   1258, 1732,-3258)

Vector starting with -ve value

x = c(-1856, 1770, 1787, 1322, 1605, 1417, 1423, 1371, 1200, 1295, 441,   587, 189, 330, 1133, 1398, 1455, 100, 455, 59, 222, 330, 289, 251, 1717,   1258, 1732,3258)

Vector with starting and ending -ve values
```

I have managed to do the job but my code is very slow. I have to run it on a very large data set and it is taking 2 hrs for single year. Any help to improve my code will be appreciated..

My code

```
drop_remo = function(x){
            if (sum(x<=0)>15){
                finalx= x[x<=0 | x>0]=0
            }else if (all(x>0)){
                finalx = x
            }else{
                newx = c(x[1:length(x)],x)
                nloc = which(newx <= 0)
                Breaks <- c(which(diff(nloc) != 1), length(nloc))
                vv = sapply(seq(length(Breaks) - 1),
                        function(n) nloc[(Breaks[n] + 1):Breaks[n+1]])

                if (is.matrix(vv)){
                    b1<-apply(vv,2,list)
                    vv = lapply(b1,unlist)
                    }
                for (i in vv){
                    #print(i)
                    backdata = newx[i[1]-1]
                    if(i[length(i)]==length(newx)){
                        smoothed = newx[length(newx)/2]
                    }else if((length(vv)==1) & (i[length(i)]==length(newx))){
                        forwarddata = newx[(i[length(i)]/2) +1]

                    }else{
                        forwarddata = newx[i[length(i)]+1]
                        smoothed = (backdata+forwarddata)/2
                    }
                    #print(backdata)    
                    #print(forwarddata)
                    #print(smoothed)
                    for (m in i){
                        newx[m] = smoothed
                    }
                 }
                finalx = newx[(length(x)+1):length(newx)]
             }
        }
```

Comment: I think your code is good.  Convert it to Rcpp and it should be fast enough instead of relying on half-baked answers

Comment: thank you akrun... I will try to modify it with Rcpp...

Comment: Maybe [interpolation](http://publish.illinois.edu/spencer-guerrero/2014/12/11/2-dealing-with-missing-data-in-r-omit-approx-or-spline-part-1/) makes sense here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using base R, could be to get index of values where `x > 0` and then take `mean` of values at `min` and `max` index.

```
inds <- which(x > 0)
x[x <=0] <- mean(c(x[min(inds)] , x[max(inds)]))
```

Or a one-liner using `range`

```
x[x<=0] <- mean(x[range(which(x > 0))])
```

---

For the updated data, we can use `ave`. Find out index which needs to be replaced (`inds`), create a grouping variable by using `diff` and `cumsum` and based on condition get the `mean`

```
inds <- which(x <= 0)
x[inds] <- ave(inds, cumsum(c(0, diff(inds)) != 1), FUN = function(i) {
           if((max(i) + 1) > length(x))
              mean(c(x[min(i) - 1], x[which.max(x > 0)]))
           else if ((min(i) - 1) <= 0)
              mean(c(x[max(which(x > 0))], x[(max(i) + 1)]))
           else 
              mean(c(x[min(i) - 1], x[(max(i) + 1)]))
           })
```

Comment: @ Ronak, Thank you for one-liner solution...so far your solution is working fine... I have to check only for edge cases and multiple missing values cases.

Comment: it is not working with multiple missing value case for example x<- c(1856,   1770, 1787,   
1322, 
1605,   
1417, 
1423,   
1371, 
1200,   
1295, 
-441,    
-587,  
-189,    
-330,  
1133,   
1398, 
1455,    
100,  
455,     
59,   
222,    
330,  
289,    
251,  
1717,   
1258, 
1732,   
-3258)

Comment: last -ve value should be replaced with 1794 mean(1856,1732) and four -ve values -441,-587,-189,-330 should be replaced with 1214 mean(1295,1133)

Comment: your latest code is not working if the missing value starts with -ve value and also ends with -ve value. my first example - c(-1856, -1770, -1787, 1322, 1605, 1417, 1423, 1371, 1200, 1295, 1441,    587, 189, 330, 1133, 1398, 1455, 100, 455, 59, 222, 330, 289, 251, 1717,   1258, 1732, -3258)

Comment: @gi.rajan I am hoping that i should have covered all the cases now? I have checked with the examples you have shared, can you do it too?

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I checked your solution it is working with my examples. now I will check whether it is taking less time than mine....